# How to know if a DNS server is an open resolver?

Tags: dns, server

I'm wondering how can I know if a DNS server is an open resolver.

Which bash command would allow me to verify that?

Comment: what's a "free DNS" ?

Comment: I thought it was the name used to define a DNS server accepting all the legal DNS requests (recursives for instance) event if it does not come from the same organization.

Comment: no, that's known as an "open resolver".   Using "dig @ip" to look up a name will give a hint, but is not something that's readily automated to prove it.  It's also off-topic for this site.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we did it in the [Zonemaster](https://github.com/dotse/zonemaster) project was to send the name server in question a `SOA` query with the `RD` flag set for the almost certainly non-existent name `xx--domain-cannot-exist.xx--illegal-syntax-tld`. If the response is `NXDOMAIN`, the name server has performed a recursive query and is therefore an open recursor. If the response is something else (`REFUSED`, `SERVFAIL` or referral to root are common) it is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I understand well google.com is not an open resolver because `host xx--domain-cannot-exist.xx--illegal-syntax-tld google.com` returns a `connection timeout`, but `37.235.1.174` is one because it returns `Host xx--domain-cannot-exist.xx--illegal-syntax-tld not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`? (It seems to be true). Can you just, please, briefly explain why the error response NXDOMAIN means that the DNS has performed a recursive query?

Comment: `NXDOMAIN` is the correct answer to the query, and in order to get it the name server must have attempted to look it up, which it would only do if it does recursive lookups for others (that is, is an open resolver). `REFUSED`, `SERVFAIL` and root-referral are different ways for a name server to say "I cannot answer that query".